# В результате работы программы не создается выходной файл

Tags: java

Ранее никогда не приходилось работать с Java, но понадобилось использовать готовый код, написанный на Java (реализация решения задачи rcpsp c ограничением на ресурсы, решение и исх. файлы взяты отсюда http://imopse.ii.pwr.wroc.pl/index.html, в разделе library, архив GARunner, +можно взять любой из исходных файлов). Код является рабочим, в итоге работы общие данные выводятся в консоль. Но программа, по идее, должна создавать выходной файл типа .sol, но по неизвестным причинам он не создается. Декомпилировав файл .jar и просмотрев  код, выяснилось, что метод, записывающий решение в файл, все же имеется.  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IJmBystDDtjTLsRpl5SRzhzYy9Q6YL2v (ссылка на декомпилированную программу). 
Буду очень благодарен, если поможете решить данную проблему

Comment: Какой класс выводить информацию в файл?

Comment: насколько понимаю,информация в файл записывается методом write в классе  MSRCPSPIO

Comment: Вы хотите переписать эту программу? Вам нужно дописать вышеуказанный класс в ваш Main в GreedyRunner

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, вызвать метод? До этого работала в основном в С#. впервые в джаве, и не знаю, как это правильней сделать
Я хочу всего лишь исправить ее так, чтобы спокойно создавался выходной файл, как и заявлено разработчиками. С самим алгоритмом, кажется, проблем нет.

Answer (score 0):

Честно, у меня не компилируется данный файл. Может быть другая JDK нужна, я использовал 8.

Но, вкратце, чтобы вывести что-то в файл, можете попробовать добавить
в начале класса `MSRCPSPGARunner`

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MSRCPSPGARunner.class.getName());
private static final String definitionFile = "assets/definitions/MSRCPSP/100_20_47_9.def";
private static final String writeFile = "assets/results/MSRCPSP/100_20_47_9/sample.sol";
```

в самый конец метода `run`

```
try {
    reader.write(resultSchedule, writeFile);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.print("Writing to a file failed");
}
 System.out.println("Time elapsed: " + (double)(endTime - startTime) / Math.pow(10.0, 9.0));
    return resultIndividuals;
```